# Force UIDataDetectorTypePhoneNumber to detect unusual phone numbers in UITextView

Tags: objective-c, uitextview, datadetectortypes

I am using the built in `setDataDetectorTypes`: method to auto-detect phone numbers in my `UITextView`s. This works great for 99% of cases for phone numbers like 1800 47 47 53.

I am setting this detection in code using the following (content is a `UITextView`):

```
        [content setDataDetectorTypes: UIDataDetectorTypePhoneNumber];
```

As expected, this method doesn't just see all number strings as phone numbers. I have a phone number in my text, "13 74 68", that is not being detected because it probably doesn't look like a phone number.

Is there any way I can force the dataDetector to see this number as a phone number? Or is there some padding/formatting I can do to the number string instead?

Comment: Just being curious: in what country is 13 74 68 a phone number?

Comment: Thanks! That's probably too short for Data Detectors to detect. (Too high a risk of false positives)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know something is going to be a phone number, you can add the `NSLinkAttributeName` attribute with a value of `tel:137468` and it's going to be handled as if it had been detected by Data Detectors.